# QueryDSL with ignore accents

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, querydsl

How can I use Java QueryDsl and ignore accents in Oracle?
With HQL I can use translate function.

```
"upper(translate({alias}." + field + ",'âàãáÁÂÀÃéêÉÊíÍóôõÓÔÕüúÜÚÇç','AAAAAAAAEEEEIIOOOOOOUUUUCC')) like (?)";
```

Comment: @rtruszk can u help me ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the same in Querydsl using

```
Expressions.stringTemplate("upper(translate({0}, 'âàãáÁÂÀÃéêÉÊíÍóôõÓÔÕüúÜÚÇç', 'AAAAAAAAEEEEIIOOOOOOUUUUCC'))")
```